# How to call a piece function from another piece

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have the pieceA that have a joinbyarray relationship with pieceB. What a I want to do is to access to the functions of pieceB in the index.js of pieceA.

I know how to access to pieceB and its fields, but I don't know how to access to their functions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make pieceB's interesting function a method on `self` in `index.js`.

in `lib/modules/piece-b/index.js`

```
  construct: function (self, options) {
    self.coolThing = function () {
      return true;
    };
  }
```

Then in pieceA's `index.js` you can access `self.apos.modules['piece-b'].coolThing`.

If you've given pieceB an `alias` property you can access it straight away as `self.apos.modules.pieceBsAlias`